# PHP imageline function doesn't work. What and how should I download?

Tags: linux, php

PHP function *imageline* on localhost works, but on VPS cloud hosting doesn't. I guess I have download something, but I don't know what. Could you give me a hand?

P.S. PHP GD is already downloaded.

Answer (score 2):

Downloaded or installed?

It isn't enough to just download it, you need to install and enable it. You didn't provide what OS is there on your VPS, so I can't say how exactly. In CentOS/RHEL/Fedora you can do it by using `yum install php-gd` (which will also add an INI file in `/etc/php.d`), restarting your web server and making sure that GD is now listed as enabled in `phpinfo()`.